# Efficient And Fastest Way to Do Sliding Window of Entire Length of The File

Tags: python, loops, sliding-window

I have a tab delimited file which contains about 2207 rows with 4 columns floats or ints types as shown below:-

```
Id    pos    value1    value2
01    1123   0.76483   0.9001
02    1124   0.20      0.9800
```

Another file is to be compared with which contains about 27041 rows with also 4 columns :-

```
name    Id    pos1    pos2
s13e    01    234     800
zz12    01    800     866
```

Now, my goal is to find **all possible consecutive rows of 3 or higher in which**:

1. Their contents of the first column of the first file (Id) are equal to the second column of the second file (Id).
2. Their contents of the second column of the first file (pos) is in between the range of column 3 and column 4 of the second file.

My approach is to do the following:

1. loop through a sliding window of length 3 to the entire length number of rows of the first file (thats my outer loop)
2. Second loop is to iterate and take each element of the sliding window of some specific length like 3 for instance and then
3. check if that element satisfy the conditions above if it is satisfy then break the loop to take the next element of the first file
4. otherwise continue searching for the second file to find the target

For a length 300 rows of the first file the whole sliding window thing with the checking to the second file takes about 5 minuets. However, I am looking for a faster and more efficient way to do that.

An example of a satisfied result is the following, lets say we have performed a window sliding of a length 3:

From file 1:

```
idW = (01,01,01)
posW = (127, 192,199)
val1W = (.9,.01,.23)
val2W = (.2,.03,.43)
```

From file 2:

```
name    Id    pos1    pos2
s13e    01    120     200
```

To result in satisfy, the following will have to be met:
posW from first file are between the values of pos1 and pos2 from file2:

consecutive rows of 3 rows **and** (true)

Id of file1 are equal file2 **and** (true)

posW are in between the values of pos1 and pos2 (true)

the result is satisfy because all conditions above are true and met

A snippet of the code is below:

```
# borrowed from one answer from stack overflow 
def sliding_window (s, n):
 it = iter(seq)
 result = tuple(islice(it, n))
 if len(result) == n:
    yield result
 for elem in it:
    result = result[1:] + (elem,)
    yield result

Ids, pos, val1, val2 = zip(*Data)
# len_Data is the entire length of the file 
for windwCounts in range(3,len_Data):
    file2count = 0
    swindow_id = sliding_window(Ids, windwCounts)
    swindow_pos = sliding_window(pos, windwCounts)
    swindow_val1 = sliding_window(val1, windwCounts)
    swindow_val2 = sliding_window(val2, windwCounts)
    slidingWindws = zip(swindow_id, swindow_pos,
                        swindow_val1, swindow_val2)
    for idW, posW, val1W, val2W in slidingWindws:
     while (file2count <= len_file2):
            name,id2,pos1,pos2 = file2[file2count]
            # No point of moving down if the pos of file1 is less than pos2 of file2
            if any(int(ps) < pos2 for ps in posW):
                    break
            # All conditions must be met:-
            ids_cond = all(a_id == id2 for a_id in idW)
            within_data = all(pos1 <= int(ps) <= pos2
                                       for ps in posW)
            if ids_cond and within_data:

                  print "satisfy"
                  break 

            else:
                  print "not satisfy"
            genesCounts += 1
```

Thanks a lot in advance, truly appreciate the help!!!

Comment: It would help if you could also show the expected outcome for your example.

Comment: @MartinEvans its a simple display of "satisfy" or "no satisfy" that's it.

Comment: Could you give a longer example which would result in `satisfy`? i.e. longer first and second file data. Also you say you want **all possible consecutive rows** but break on the first match, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @MartinEvans I have added an example of one instance which result in satisfy, and also explained all possible connective rows, please inform me if it does make sense. Note that no satisfy is otherwise. Thanks a lot, Martin!

Comment: @aBiologist any possibility you could use `pandas`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure if I can do that with such module!